# Emulator in tizen TV

Tags: emulation

I am trying to launch emulator but nothing is happening and when I tried to install it from package manager the installation fails
I am not able to launch emulator to test the app.

I tried to install it through package manager but the installation fails
i think my exe is missing but how to add this.

Comment: Would you share your test environment and more detailed information? Ubuntu XX.XX version, Windows XX version, Mac xx version, which guide page you used, etc

Comment: Have you followed guide page? https://docs.tizen.org/application/tizen-studio/setup/install-sdk/